# Commit through curl command is causing delay in issuing commit on solr-8.5.2

Tags: solr, lucene, apache-zookeeper, solrj, solrcloud

Solr Setup: (Running in solrCloud mode)
It has 6 shards, and each shard has only one replica (which is also a
leader) and the replica type is NRT.
Each shards are hosted on the separate physical host.

Zookeeper => We are using external zookeeper ensemble (3 separate node
cluster)

Shard and Host name:  shard1_0=solr_199;  shard1_1=solr_200; shard2_0=solr_254 ; shard2_1=solr_132;  shard3_0=solr_133; shard3_1=solr_198

*Request rate on the system is currently zero and only hourly indexing
running on it.*

We are using curl command to issue commit.

> /curl
> "http://solr_254:8389/solr/my_collection/update?openSearcher=true&commit=true&wt=json"/

(Here we are using solr_254 host to issue commit)

> 2020-12-06 18:47:47.013 ERROR
> org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: Timeout occured
> while waiting response from server at:
> http://solr_132:9744/solr/my_collection_shard2_1_replica_n21/update?update.distrib=TOLEADER&distrib.from=http%3A%2F%2Fsolr_254%3A9744%2Fsolr%2Fmy_collection_shard2_0_replica_n11%2F
> at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.Http2SolrClient.request(Http2SolrClient.java:407)
> at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.Http2SolrClient.request(Http2SolrClient.java:753)
> at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.ConcurrentUpdateHttp2SolrClient.request(ConcurrentUpdateHttp2SolrClient.java:369)
> at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.request(SolrClient.java:1290)
> at org.apache.solr.update.SolrCmdDistributor.doRequest(SolrCmdDistributor.java:344)
> at org.apache.solr.update.SolrCmdDistributor.lambda$submit$0(SolrCmdDistributor.java:333)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedRunnable.run(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:180)
> at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:210)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
> at org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.InputStreamResponseListener.get(InputStreamResponseListener.java:216)
> at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.Http2SolrClient.request(Http2SolrClient.java:398)
> ... 13 more

> Above timeout error is between solr_254 and solr_132. Similar errors
> are there between solr_254 and other 4 shards

Since query load is zero, mostly CPU utilization is around 3%.
After issuing curl commit command, CPU goes up to 14% on all shards except
shard2_0 (host: solr_254, the one used in curl command).
And after 10 minutes (i.e after getting the `start commit` request)  CPU  on
shard2_0 also goes up to 14%.

As I mentioned earlier each shards take around 10-12 mins to process commit
and due to delay in starting commit process on one shard (shard2_0) our
overall commit time is doubled now. (22-24 minutes approx)

In our solr-5.4.0(having similar setup), we use similar curl command
to issue commit and there all the shards are getting `start commit` request
at same time. Including the one used in curl command.

I'm not able to figure out why this is happening? Is there something changed
in internal functioning when we issue commit through curl? Is it do
something with HTTP2? We do not use autoCommit feature available in
solrconfig.xml. Its not suitable for our system. Apart from curl command are
there any other alternate ways to issue commit?

Comment: Instead of reposting your question here, I suggest taking it to the `solr-user` mailing list with your extended logs showing the problem. It'll get you a different audience instead.

Comment: Hey @MatsLindh, already added this to solr-user mailing list. Btw can you suggest what other options we have to issue commit, other than configuring autoCommit in solrconfig.xml and the curl command.

Comment: I don't think _how you issue_ the commit is the problem; that would be the same in any case. Many use `commitWithin` instead of an explicit commit, but I don't think that would change anything - the commit will still happen as it does now.

Comment: @MatsLindh Is there any drawback of using `commitWithin`? Does it impact query latency, since `commitWithin` settings forces document commits to happen in a defined time period.

Comment: It'd have the same impact as regular commits, depending on your update pressure.